# Laravel 5: Fetch comments

Tags: php, sql, laravel, get, comments

I am building a blog commenting system.

I want to show user's comments in show.blade.php.

In my ResultsController I executed

> dd($post->comments);

But I cannot retrieve any comments from my database.

I seeded four comments to a post. 
And user can reply to each one comment.

migration table

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('post_id');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->integer('comment_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment.php

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'comment_id')->whereNotNull('comment_id');
}
```

Post.php

```
 public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)->whereNull('comment_id');
}
```

User.php

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

Mysql
[image: I seeded 4 comments to a post(id=52)]

ResultsController.php

```
 public function show($id,Post $post)
{
    $particular_post= Post::find($id);
    $recommended_posts = Post::latest()
                            ->whereDate('date','>',date('Y-m-d'))
                            ->where('category_id','=',$particular_post->category_id)
                            ->where('id','!=',$particular_post->id)
                            ->limit(7)
                            ->get();

    $posts['particular_post'] = $particular_post;
    $posts['recommended_posts'] = $recommended_posts;

    dd($post->comments);

    return view('posts.show',compact('posts'));
}
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/results/52 
This is the URL which supposed to fetch comments.

Comment: `->whereNull('comment_id')` Shouldn't that be `->whereNotNull('comment_id')`?

Comment: why`whereNull`?

Comment: Because I want to fetch only first comments. Each comment has comment_id, it is a reply to one comment.

Comment: @kerbholz I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: `return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)->limit(1)` to fetch single comment

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work.

Comment: Your relations are fine, it's probably the method injection, what does your Route mapping to the controller look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method injections only work when the variable in the route mapping and the argument for the function have the same name, you also only have to accept the post itself as an argument, you don't need both the post and the id of it.

Change your `show` function to this:

```
public function show(Post $post)
{
    $recommended_posts = Post::latest()
                            ->whereDate('date','>',date('Y-m-d'))
                            ->where('category_id','=',$post->category_id)
                            ->where('id','!=',$post->id)
                            ->limit(7)
                            ->get();

    $posts['particular_post'] = $post;
    $posts['recommended_posts'] = $recommended_posts;

    dd($post->comments);

    return view('posts.show',compact('posts'));
}
```

And then make sure the variable in the route mapping has the same name as the argument to `show`, ie:

```
Route::get('results/{post}', 'ResultsController@show');
```